# How did mathematicans prove things before ZFC or Peano

Tags: math-history, foundations, peano-axioms

I do not get it. How was a+b=b+a or a (b +c) = ab + ac proved by ancient mathematicians before set theory or Peano axioms? If you cannot logically prove the laws of arithmetic without Peano or set theory then how did  ancient mathematians have confidence in claiming laws of math?

Ive seen a video (on youtube) proving a*b=b*a using intuitive graphical methods etc, such as imagine a rectangle with sides the units of the the two numbers being multiplied and then rotate it and youve proved a*b=b*a. Which i consider a proof because how else did they prove it. But commentors say this isnt a proof it doesnt use set theory etc. If math is based on proof and all about being able to prove your assertions then what was math prior to set theory? A bunch of no proven guesses? How did mathematicans have any confidence in a*b=b*c by way of mathematical proof? Surely they had a way of proving it (a*b=b*a) 2000 years ago without set theory or peano axioms as neither set theory or peano existed then? And if so how did they prove it?

@Andrés E. Caicedo's comment below: correct. So what axiomatic system did they develop to prove basic laws of arithmetic? Thats my question. And if they didnt how was what they were doing math it was conjecture only as they lacked a proof and it didnt come until 2000 years later with peano and zfc

Im getting the idea they had no proof as we know it today  and accepted them as axioms or true because you can tell something like ab = ba is true in your mind even if you cannot necessarily write down exactly why deductively at the level of zfc or peano and this is what they did to establish much of mathematics.

Comment: Ancient mathematicians simply assumed most of the basics. Peano and set theory came about relatively late in the history of math, - the 19th century or so - as the desire to give a strong foundation to math. Even Euclid, a partial effort to formalize geometry, was missing a fair amount of the foundations of geometry (you have to wait until Hilbert to fill in the holes.)

Comment: They were just axioms.  You have to start somewhere.

Comment: Euclid's proof , that infinite many primes exist , for example, is crystal-clear and needs no formalism to convince.

Comment: I think it is a mistake to conceive of mathematics as something that can only be developed axiomatically. This is typically not how things occur. Axiomatizations typically occur after intuitions are developed and after it is clear that there will be benefits to the formalization process.

Comment: Even Andrew Wiles did not prove Fermat's last theorem "formally" !

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Good argument ! Therefore we need not worry whether statements like $\ 2\cdot 2=4\ $ are actually true despite Goedel's results.

Comment: Note a very important fact : mathematics was (and still is, even if formalism makes it seems less true, it is still very much the case) a social activity. Therefore a proof is not here to convince the almighty god of maths (would that be Grothendieck ?), but it's here to convince other mathematicians. Standards of proof evolve, and so what once convinced mathematicians doesn't anymore. Formalism helps us give a basis for what should and what shouldn't convince us; but it's still about convincing. (Cont')

Comment: (Cont') for instance I'm way more convinced by the usual, unformalized proof of the infinitude of primes of Euclid, than by Russell's completely formal proof of $1+1=2$, simply because I cannot read the second. Surely given time, I could read it and would probably agree, but I'm way more confident in the possibility of turning Euclid's argument into a formal one than in Russell's proof. Note that completely formalized proofs can be subject to mistakes : if you misapply a rule at some point, or if the computer that checks it has a bug/is ill-programmed

Comment: My point is that no matter how many layers of formalism/computer checking/human peer reviewing you put in, there's always the possibility that at some point in the process something/someone made an error : in the end it all comes down to what convinces you. It so happens that formalism  and computer checking makes it easier to be convinced because the possibilities of making a mistake are lowered - but it's still about convincing.

Comment: Why are all the answers in comnents?

Comment: Are the downvotes of this question because it is a soft-question? Why not just suggest a tag improvement?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo If they were having conjectures (intuitions) without ever proving them isnt that missing the major part that makes math... math... the rigourous proof part. So were statements like a*b=b*a considered conjectures until 2000 years later when someone invented set theory or peano and proved them? I find it hard to believe. I think they had some kind of proof back then? And if it was a satisfying proof then it must of been mathematics they were doing as opposed to science or something else. And if they had such proof why cant we use their proofs as sufficient? And where are they?

Comment: @AlbertoTakase Questions that can't  be answered by churning out a proof seem to automatically get downvotes. I don't know why.

Comment: @Noanswersatisfies I think you would benefit from reading a book about the rise of formalism in the 19th century. Again, mathematics is something much more organic and malleable than your comments would suggest.

Comment: @Noanswersatisfies Here are [Euclid"s proofs](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/) with commentary on them, anyway.

Comment: Given all the various forms of intuitionism and constructivism that exist, I can easily imagine someone 50 years from now questioning, as you are now, how people in the early 21st century managed to prove anything without specifying exactly what underlying rules of reasoning were being used. And 50 years after that, people wondering how those in the middle 21st century managed to prove anything without specifying what type of [Grok'ness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) the proof was intended for (unaided human biological brains, various types of artificial intelligences, etc.).

Comment: You're making a lot of assumptions about how people historically did mathematics. Have you *read* any old mathematical texts? That will give you some sense of what the activity actually looked like. At the same time, you should also read some *modern* mathematical texts, to see how purely formal proof does (or more generally, *doesn't*) play a role in actual modern practice. Basically, it seems you're trying to do history from a purely theoretical perspective, and that's not going to work well.

Comment: Specifically, your most recent comment makes the following key assumptions: rigorous proof is what makes mathematics mathematics, and our criteria for what constitutes a rigorous proof don't change over time ("if it was a satisfying proof  ... why cant we use their proofs as sufficient?"). The first criterion is arguable, and the second is simply false. I think all this will be helped by reading some of the actual primary sources, not necessarily with an eye towards the specific mathematical *methods* but rather focusing on the *language and argument structure* they employ.

Comment: Thanks for input guys. Im gathering the answer is they did not have formal deductive proofs for things like a*b=b*a.

Comment: And intuition for such laws as a*b=b*a was enough for them back then as proof. So much so most of basic math was built up on it. Then later on 1000s of years later people made systems to deduce deductively the basic stuff they had never deduced deductively to formally prove it. And now those proofs are the only ones accepted as true. It seems odd to me as i guess i thought the greeks established that math had to proved deductivley yet basic laws were not for 2000 years until zfc and peano

Comment: Do you have a proof for ZFC? Or for the Peano axioms? Of course not. When doing math, we (generally) assume without mention that what we're doing can be done in ZFC. Did mathematicians prove that $ab=ba$? Of course not. When doing math, they (generally) assumed without mention that that can be done.

Comment: Moreover, it's not the case that laws such as $ab=ba$ and $1+1=2$ ultimately come from ZFC and some axioms. It is the other way around; ZFC and these axioms have been designed to formalize all these facts that we already *know* to be true.

Comment: @Servaes you said we *know* them to be true. By *know* you mean they seem true in the mind when thinking about them i.e. ab=ba, and because we need to start somewhere, we just accept them as being true and keep doing math, right?